# Firebase Auth/unauthorized domain. Domain is not authorized

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run this [sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users) firebase project, but I keep getting this error in the browser console.

```
Lf {code: "auth/unauthorized-domain", message: "This domain (mail-demo-fcm.firebaseapp.com) is not…se console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab."}

code: "auth/unauthorized-domain"

message: "This domain (mail-demo-fcm.firebaseapp.com) is not authorized to run this operation. Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab."
```

I have enabled Google in Authentication -> Sign-in Method as sign-in providers.

[image]

Am I missing something ?

A little guide will be helpful.

And I am using Firebase's free plan.

Comment: Also don`t use IP addresses as URL here. **Instead of 127.0.0.1, use localhost**.

Answer (score 154):

You need to add domain `mail-demo-fcm.firebaseapp.com` to
Authentication menu in Firebase at Authorized domains

[image]

Comment: There's no "Authorized domains" section. It jumps straight to "Advanced"

Comment: Go to Authorization > Settings (top tab) > Domains (left-hand-side and below) > Authorized Domains

Comment: I am trying to add this with vite react app and url generated for localhost is http://127.0.0.1:5173/ but it is not allowed to be added in whitelisting of firebase. Could u suggest please?

Comment: @Clinto_92_Abraham I used my IP address without the port number and it worked fine. In your case you'd need to only put 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 12):

The authorized domains section might also be in the settings page. Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of firebase authorized domains]

Comment: I had a problem adding sub domain to the "Authorized Domains". Finally it worked by adding the main domain to "Authorized Domains"

Answer (score 11):

If localhost is already in the list of domains, make sure you're accessing your test app via http://localhost/ and not http://127.0.0.1/

Comment: This was a lifesaver !

Comment: Wohh, I was struggling to figure this out. Thanks you saved a ton of headache!

Comment: what do you mean by list of domains?

Answer (score 7):

Below the sign-in method section, there is a Authorized domains section. I think you need to whitelist your domain there.

Comment: There's no such section. https://imgur.com/a/Igusaun

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Firebase
2. Go to console
3. Open your project
4. Go to Authentication
5. sign-in-method
6. Add domain

Try it!

In my case it's working

Answer (score 1):

Enable localhost and your own domain that you are using in the firebase console.

1. Login into firebase
2. Click on the authentication tab
3. Add authorized domains

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @alkas was helpful, but I also needed to explicitly enable the Sign-in providers for my app (Email/Password, Google, etc) for this error to go away

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found the problem after deleting localhost from my "Authorized domains".

So I just add it (localhost), so everything is okay !

-localhost, because I'm on local,

-project_name.firebase.com and project_name.web.app when app deployed.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use two environments for development and testing. By mistake, I deployed the build to the testing environment, which was created using the development configuration parameters.