# Firebase "this domain is not authorized to run this operation" error, yet also no "authorized websites" section

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Error message when attempting to sign in via google as a would-be end user in my website:

> This domain (maxloh.com) is not authorized to run this operation. Add
> it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth
> section -> Sign in method tab.

A pre-existing tells me to go into [Authorized Domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076968/firebase-auth-unauthorized-domain-domain-is-not-authorized).
Yet there is no such section: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke4v5.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is some change in the layout. You can find the section to add Authorized Domains in Firebase console > Auth section > Settings > Authorized Domains

Answer (score 0):

[see this picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4exm.png)

just go to firebase Auth then > settings > authorized domains > add your Hosted app link or if you are testing the app on local host just add localhost.