# Adding "Authorized domains" section is missing from the Firebase Authentication console

Tags: firebase, authentication, dns, console

1. I need to add authorized domains to my Firebase Authentication project.
2. The documentation says there are fields to add authorized domains in the console at a certain place. However, when you go there, it is not there. The documentation appears to be out of date and incorrect.

[[IMAGE] Screenshot of Firebase documentation as of 2022-11-30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaY4k.png)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth?authuser=2&hl=en

When you navigate there, notice how it's completely missing:

[[IMAGE] Screenshot of Firebase Authentication Console, Sign-in Methods tab as of 2022-11-30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOHEa.png)

I've seen screenshots online where it appears, but perhaps those are old screenshots.

1. I tried navigating to the place in my Firebase console where the documentation told me to go.
2. It is not there.

Comment: I was in same issue and find in this link.
[check it!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076968/firebase-auth-unauthorized-domain-domain-is-not-authorized)

Answer (score 3):

Now you can find it on **authentication -> settings tab**